# Would it be possible to include the original author of the question even if it has been modified?

Tags: discussion, moderation, questions

I found it odd that on the first page of the Java tagged questions, I cannot see any author, only the user who last modified the question. I understand the value that modifications add (provide an answer, fix a tag, format the code, etc), but I think it is unfair and also weird that the original author of the question is not there. It seems that all questions belong to 3 or 4 persons who perform all the modifications, and the knowledge added by the person who originally asked the question seems to be less important than the modifications made by other users.

Maybe the site should display both pieces of information (added by and modified by)?

[image: a screenshot of the Questions page]

Comment: In the "Recently Modified" view, the name shown is the last person to "bump" the question (by editing or answering); it's rarely an actual moderator. And if you sort by "Newest", it shows the original author instead.

Comment: That's dumb. It shouldn't matter how you sort, IMHO. It should show the originator of the questions regardless. And if the last person who edited a question isn't the OP, then it should show that info as the last modifier.

Comment: +1 for the clarity of the question. I think it was like that in the first versions of SO engine, but it was removed IIRC to be the way it is now, which btw I like better.

Comment: To the OP: the image attached to this post needs to be re-uploaded.

Comment: I will take a new screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mmyers noted in his comment, what is shown here is specific to the sort order you've specified.

Choose "newest", you get the original author.

Choose "recent", you get the last person to modify it.

Comment: As always, mmyers providing an excellent answer in a comment. @Jeff I if you add reputation to upvoted comments mmyers would be the next Jon Skeet. ;)